# Oracle database rollback after update

Tags: database, oracle

After upgrading from 11g to 12c, we noticed a weird behaviour. When we update a table, the data is rolled back though we issued commit and there was no error.

Anyone with similar experience?

Comment: HAve you checked for any trigger?

Comment: Query the ORA_ROWSCN for the records before and after the update. If the value has incremented, then changes were applied and possibly reversed. If it stays the same, then it was a rollback. 
Was the database part of a replicated environment (dataguard / standby) where another database may have taken on the primary role ?

Comment: Some interesting observations, it seems to be some insert condition that trigger this. Our developer team simulated 2 insertion follow by the update, and it succeeded. PS: the update is local table, insert is remote insertion over db link

Answer (score 0):

This is never supposed to happen: once the database receives a COMMIT request, it must either (1) fulfill the COMMIT request or (2) return an error AND roll back the transaction.  Oracle (version 12C) has an API called "Transaction Guard" that is supposed to notify you if a commit is successful.  Here is the URL for that API:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT89217

Even if you are Not using this API, if the transaction reaches the ORACLE database, it should 
either succeed or you should receive a listener or ORA- error.

Are you sure that:

- You are using a client that does not roll back if part of the data for a transaction (E.G. one field in a data grid) is not filled out
- Is your ORACLE client compatible with 12C?